# How to sort a map based on key using a separate sort list as input in groovy? The sort list is dynamic and can change for every API call

Tags: groovy

How to sort a map based on key using a separate sort list as input in groovy? The sort list is dynamic and can change for every API call.

```
"preference": [81224, 40281, 30452, 30003, 44291, 32818],
"orders": {
    "30452": {
        "id": "l0089",
        "program": "ll",
        "tier": "2"
    },
    "40281": {
        "id": "88ds1",
        "program": "alm",
        "tier": "1"
    },
    "81224": {
        "id": "a0d0001",
        "program": "ccc",
        "tier": "4"
    },
    "32818": {
        "id": "a1212",
        "program": "alm",
        "tier": "4"
    },
    "44291": {
        "id": "37000",
        "program": "acm",
        "tier": "5"
    },
    "30003": {
        "id": "a1421",
        "program": "cld",
        "tier": "2"
    }
}
```

I tried something like this orders.sort{ preference.contains(it) as Comparator}

Answer (score 1):

If `preference` contains all orders then following could be used:

```
def sorted = preference.collectEntries{
    [ it, orders[it] ]
}
```

Comment: Even if the `orders` map does not contain all the `preference` keys you could do something like this instead: `... = preference.intersect(orders.keySet()).collectEntries ...`.

OTOH, if there are map keys that are not in the `preference` list, you would have to do something more complicated (assuming you know what you want to happen in that case).